# generateSchema in JPA

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm very new to JPA and this project is not mine.
I see there are some test classes in `./test` directory. When I try to run `mvn clean package` the build fails indeed for the tests: I do not have the mysql db the test classes uses.
I found a class `CreateSchema` in a test package but if I run it no db is created. I even tried to manually create the db, in this case the build prints erros about mysql tables missing.

This is the class

```
package com.myproject.test;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class CreateSchema {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Persistence.generateSchema("MySchema", null);
    }
}
```

When I run it it prints absolutely nothing.

What am I missing?

This is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartid</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.28</version>
    <description>Jaxb libs dependencies managed and cleaned</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/META-INF</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/persistence.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>test</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/META-INF/persistence.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- explicitly define maven-deploy-plugin after other to force exec 
                    order -->
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mod4j.org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MySchema" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>com.myproj.jpa.class1</class>
        <class>com.myproj.jpa.class1</class>
        <class>...</class>
        <!-- other classes-->

        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpaexample" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="10000" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min"
                value="5" />
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max"
                value="200" />
            <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage"
                value="dev" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Missing ? Missing posting the persistence.xml, missing posting the entities that you have specified in persistence.xml, missing posting which JPA provider, missing posting what is in the JPA providers log when you execute that

Comment: I edited the question with pom and persistence.xml

Comment: yes, but you dont say what happens. If there is an error then post the error + stack trace. If not then look in the LOG of your chosen JPA provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done this with maven, although I've used a couple of properties on the persistence.xml to get the .sql files for my entities.

```
 <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
 <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script"/>
 <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="${TARET_DIR}"/>
 <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="schema.sql"/>
 <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="drop-schema.sql"/>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question was about how to make that `main` method works. As workaround I indeed generated DDL in Eclipse..